# Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 5, and with leading coefficient 1.

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 5, and with leading coefficient 5. If further that f(1)=1, , f(2)=3, f(3)=5, f(4)=7,  f(5)=9. What is the value of f(6)?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the polynomial $g(x) = f(x)-x$. This has degree $5$ with leading coefficient one and its roots are $1,2,3,4,5$. Hence, we have
$$g(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$
This means
$$f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5) + x$$
I trust now you can obtain $f(6)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)-x=0$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5$, so $f(x)-x=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$.

Plugging $x=6$ in gives $f(6)-6=120$, so $f(6)=126$.

Comment: The answer is true...no downvote needed!!!...+1

Comment: I like this answer since it shows the motivation for taking that polynomial! +1